# Stop and Start Tomcat to test Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I just built a tiny test web app with a servlet as so:

***index.html --> servlet (doPost) --> redirect to results page***

Where the index page is a simple form that calls the servlet via doPost when its 'submit' button is clicked. Then after a business method runs in the servlet (with the form data) a redirect to a results page appears.

I exported my project as a war to my tomcat 7 /webapps dir and start the container. Everything runs great!

**Question:**
However, why do I have to stop then start Tomcat every time I want to retest the form? That is, if I click 'Back' from the results page to the form page (index.html) and hit the refresh button in firefox, I can fill out a fresh form, but when I click submit again the business logic function never runs in the servlet unless I restart the container?

*index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>URL Auction Search Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<CENTER>
 <FORM ACTION="/ResultServlet/Results" METHOD=GET>
   <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="st">
   <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=Submit>
  </FORM>
</CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

*Servlet*

```
@WebServlet("/Results")
public class Results extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       public static String str="";

    private String businessLogic(String q){
        try {
            str = new compute.URL.GetAvailURI( "https://www.registerdomains.com/auctionAPI/Key:a05u3***1F2r6Z&urlSearch="+q);
            /*more boring number crunching */
            return str;
            }
/*
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    }
*/
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Results r = new Results();
        String st = request.getParameter("st");
        response.sendRedirect("results/resultActionURL.html?st="+r.businessLogic(st)");

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens exactly when the form is submitted?

Comment: doPost gets the fields, calls a method with the fields as arguments, then redirects to a results page with an argument (customer name&address) in the url that the results page grabs in js and displays

Comment: But what happens when you submit the form the second time? You say that the "business logic function" is not executed. What happens instead?

Comment: I get: http://localhost:8080/TinyTestServlet/Confirmation And there is nothing in the browser (blank white screen),  Where normally I would get http://localhost:8080/TinyTestServlet/Confirmation/results.html?str=02%blahblahblah02%...

Comment: Show us the code. Debug it. Add logs to understand what happens. We can't guess without seeing anything.

Comment: Check the logs. FYI, using a static, or even an instance, variable like this in a servlet is a Really Bad Idea--it will be shared across all requests.

Comment: OK, very good to know- thank you! Ill start in on the logs...

Comment: Changed the static class String to a String inside local method. thank you again.

Comment: UMMMMM? I changed NOTHING else, but the static String and all of the sudden my problem is solved. Everything works now! Could the scope of a String have been the problem? If so- can you pls post as an answer

Comment: FYI, I rolled back the question's code to the original code that showed the problem. A question with working code is kind of useless.

Comment: Ive learned 2 good things from you now, thank you. Will not change in the future. Can you post the String comment as an answer so that I can accept? Or is it impossible that was what solved it? I literally changed nothing but the scope of the String and now its working...